# Spring aspectj implications

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm working on a project which has an aspect and has a `@EnableAspectJ` on a configuration.

It means all proxies of spring are created using aspectj? What happen then with `@Transactional` and `@Async`? Should it has mode attribute set to use aspectJ ? Or it will uses CGLIB and Aspectj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html) you need to set `proxyTargetClass=true` to use CGLIB proxies else standard JDK interface based proxies will be used.

> Users can control the type of proxy that gets created for FooService using the proxyTargetClass() attribute. The following enables CGLIB-style 'subclass' proxies as opposed to the default interface-based JDK proxy approach.

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
 public class AppConfig {
   // ...
 }
```